# How to convert the jsonb datatype to other datatype in psql for amazon quicksight

Tags: report, psql, amazon-quicksight

My Psql database has a table which has **jsonb** as type for some columns, when i tried to upload these tables in amazon **quicksight** for some analysis purpose, am getting an error says **unsupported datatype** and the columns are getting **skipped** in amazom Quicksight. 
Please help me to convert these into some supported type in amazon Quicksight.

```
Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default
```

---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('solera_progresses_id_seq'::regclass)
 milestones    | jsonb                       |           |          | 
 reference_id  | character varying           |           |          | 
 response_code | integer                     |           |          | 
 activity      | jsonb                       |           |          | 
 response      | jsonb                       |           |          | 
 user_id       | bigint                      |           |          |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom SQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-SQL-query.html) to convert the data to the supported type before loading to Quicksight.

For instance, if your jsonb column contains objects like `{"name": "John"}`, you can create a column `name` in Quicksight using the query:

```sql
SELECT column_name->'name' AS name
FROM table_name
```